# Iframe click make div show hide

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have an iframe on which it opens a page which has three links.

I want to show the div on one of its links. Please suggest what to do.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="divTest" runat="server" >
    this is a test div          // Hide this div
</div>

<div class="inner-ca" style="width: 981px;">
    <div class="main" style="width: 932px;">
        <div id="page_FAQ">
            <a href="LocatorDefault.aspx" runat="server" style="float: right; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 4px; text-decoration: underline; color: #666;" target="_blank">To have a full view click here</a>
            <h2>Locate Us</h2>
            <div class="box1_bot">
                <div class="box1_left">
                    <div class="box1_right">
                        <div class="box1" style="border:0px;">
                            <iframe src="Default.aspx" width="100%" height="675" style="position: relative;"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain JS assuming both pages from same origin.
I gave the iFrame an ID and an onload

[Working example](http://plungjan.name/SO/testif.html)

```
function assignHandler() {
  var ifr = document.getElementById("iframe1");
  var iframeDocument = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
  var links=iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function() {
      var div = parent.document.getElementById("divTest");
      if (div) div.style.display=this.href.indexOf("Locker")!=-1?"block":"none";
      return false; // remove when link is needed
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: `Iframe` is not having any `ID`. In all there are three pages. I want to show the div only on one page. Will that work ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If there is a link and it can be clicked, you decide which to click. My code lives in the iFrame. If you need to assign the click from the parent, please say so

Comment: Sir, Scenario, I have a Iframe from where a default page is called. In that page, I have `three links`. I have to show that div in one of the click. Hope you got

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. But you do not tell me if the parent has to assign the event handler. I assigned the event handler inside the `Default.aspx`

Comment: Ok. let me try and check.. Also bydefault it will he hidden, it will be visible only on one of the links

Comment: yes sir that works in the default page where I have given the link. But I want that for the page where my `Iframe` is written

Comment: Since you did not post the content of the Default.asp - link1 is the ID *I* gave the link. If there is no ID, change it to `.....getElementsByTagName("a")[2]` or whatever points at the actual link you are trying to access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75815/discussion-between-nadeem-and-mplungjan).

Comment: sir, let me know once you back

Comment: OK, let me check and test on myside